# ¿Cómo usar un modelo y un IEnumerable en una misma vista con asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc, tablas, vistas

Estoy trabajando una vista en 'asp.net' con 'razor', tengo un inconveniente a la hora de usar un modelo, puesto que para traer datos a un 'modal' uso un modelo, pero al momento de ejecutar una tabla, es decir, una vista de los datos de esa misma tabla llamo a un model 'IEnumerable' de el mismo modelo que uso para guardar y traer datos.

Esta es mi vista:

```html
@model PasantiasUtec.Models.empresas

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.idempresa)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.empresa)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.giro)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.nomEncargado)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.direccion)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.telefono)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.correo)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.idempresa)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.empresa)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.giro)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.nomEncargado)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.direccion)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.telefono)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.correo)
            </td>
            <td>
                <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" class="btn btn-danger" href="@Url.Action("editar", "Empresa", new { id = item.idempresa })">Editar</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>

@* Creación de el modal*@
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">

            @* Modal del titulo*@
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Editar</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>

            @* Cuerpo del modal*@
            <div class="modal-body">

                @* El Action del form se conecta con la función del controller, sin el action no entra a la función*@
                <form action="/Empresa/editar" method="post">
                    @using (Html.BeginForm())
                    {
                        <div class="form-row" style="padding-left:12px">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-2" aria-hidden="true">
                                <label for="lidempresa">idEmpresa</label>
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.idempresa, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                                <label for="lempresa">Empresa</label>
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.empresa, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                                <label for="lnomEncargado">Encargado</label>
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.nomEncargado, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row" style="padding-left:9px">

                            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                                <label for="ltelefono">Telefono</label>
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.telefono, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row" style="padding-left:9px">
                            <div class="mb-3 col-md-10">
                                <label for="lgiro">Giro</label>
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.giro, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            </div>

                            <div class="mb-3 col-md-10">
                                <label for="ldireccion">Direccion</label>
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.direccion, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row float-right">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                            <input type="submit" name="Guardar" class="btn btn-danger" value="Guardar" style="margin-left:5px" />
                        </div>
                    }
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Así como está no genera error en el 'modal' y los 'Html.EditorFor' pero sí en el 'for each' de la tabla donde se muestran los datos, ese 'for each' se pone normal cuando tengo este modelo:

```html
@model IEnumerable<PasantiasUtec.Models.empresas>
```

Con ese modelo la tabla me va bien, pero me da error en los 'Html.EditorFor' porque no encuentra el modelo, no estoy muy orientado al 'mvc' ni tengo mucha experiencia, les estaré agradecido si alguien me brinda alguna opinión o ayuda, intenté hacer una clase con los dos modelos pero no sé si lo hice bien o no se puede porque el 'IEnumerable' viene de la misma clase de modelo empresas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si entedi bien, en una pagina quieres tanto mostrar la informacion como crear un nuevo registro, para esto debes crear un ViewModel y pasarselo a la vista de la siguiente manera

```
public class RegistrosViewModel
{
     public List<Empresas> Empresas { get; set; }
     public Empresas NuevaEmpresa { get; set; }
}
```

Donde a la lista de empresas la usas en el ciclo, y el campo NuevaEmpresa la usas en el formulario. En el controlador simplemente llenas el ViewModel con los datos que le queiras pasar a la vista.

```
 public ActionResult VerYCrearRegistros()
 {
      RegistrosViewModel model = new RegistrosViewModel{
          Empresas = _dbContext.Empresas.ToList(),
          NuevaEmpresa = new Empresa()
      };

      return View(model);
 }
```

Comment: Gracias, me funciono bien en la vista, ahora tengo otro inconveniente al momento de llamar un la función que me actualizará los datos en el modal, pero espero encontrarle solución